# Getting rows count as zero after slecting data from where = date as using distinct above

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, where-clause

Hi am retreiving the distinct dates then am trying to retreive the rows with that dates but am getting them as zero..
Here is code

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  date FROM video_data ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $date = $row['date'];
  echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>$date</td>";
         $query_order = "SELECT * FROM video_data WHERE date=$date";
         $query_order_total = mysqli_query($connection,$query_order);
         var_dump($query_order);
         $total =  mysqli_num_rows($query_order_total);
     echo "<td>$total</td>";
  echo"<tr>";
```

But when am selecting `"SELECT * FROM video_data"` its showing correct count

Comment: updated question at bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing ' ' around $date

`$query_order = "SELECT * FROM video_data WHERE date='$date'";`

That said: when you have, let's say, 60 dates found in your first query, you will than fire 60 new queries to find the actual data.

how about:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total, date 
        FROM video_data 
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>". $row['date'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $row['total']. "</td>";
  echo"<tr>";
}
```

Comment: thanks its working i will accept after 10 minutes as am not able to accept now

Comment: consider executing only 1 query, not 1 per date found